# Spectral Distribution Function Related to Energy Density

Tags: thermal-radiation

I'm a little confused as to why the Energy Density of a black body is related, in particular by $4/C$, to the spectral distribution function. One is per area, while the other is per volume, I'm lost. I'm reading Bransden, page 4 if any one needs a reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert the radiance of a body (W/m$^2$/sr) into an energy density (J/m$^3$), you need to consider two things:

- imagine that a "surface" of radiation moves at $c$. During a time $t$, it will occupy the volume $V=S\,c\,t$. So, to convert the energy per time $t$ per surface $S$ into the energy inside the volume $V$, the factor is $1/c$.
- You have to add a factor $4\pi$ to account for the fact that the radiance is per unit solid angle.

Alright this is not a proper mathematical proof, but the result ends up with a factor $4\pi/c$.
There are more details [here](http://www.astrohandbook.com/ch14/radiation_defs.pdf).